# Angular JS prevent $watch listener

Tags: angularjs

I've use dropdown list which render some results via `$scope.$watch` listener callback in Angular JS controller.

When i change dropdown list other value it works fine.
But in some case i need to keep last selected results(does not need rise that event).

I've tried `ng-change` and `ng-click` but it works after
`$scope.$watch` raised.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please include some code samples.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload on `$scope.$watch()` where you can also capture the previous value of the watched property.

```
$scope.$watch(propertyExpression, newValue, oldValue)
```

Is this what you are looking for? It is hard to read your mind without code samples ;)

If you want to keep even older values, you might want to consider keeping some state in your controller.

BTW, it can be interesting to always use this overload and check first whether the object you are watching really changed using `(newValue !== oldValue)` because (if I recall correctly) `$scope.$watch` is also triggered when `$scope.$apply` is called on a higher level node.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works,

```
var unregisterWatch =
    $scope.$watch('param', function(newVal, oldVal) {
           if (newVal === oldVal) 
              return; // 
           });
```

call this function when required, it will cancel Angular's watch on the variable.